# Display Decision Tree in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a visual of my decision tree.

```
dot = export_graphviz(c50_01, 
                out_file = "C:/.../c50_01.dot")
graph3 = graphviz.Source(dot)
graph3
```

I receive this error:

```
failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

I have added C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe to my environmental variables but I receive the same error. I have also ensured graphvix is installed with pip and conda commands.

Comment: You should add C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin to your PATH.

Comment: @enzo could you please explain how to do this? Sorry I am new to python

Comment: @enzo could you please explain how to do this? Sorry I am new to python

Comment: Hi Tara, no Python needed. You said you've added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe" to your environment variables, right? Just remove the "dot.exe" from the end.

Comment: For some reason this is still not working for me. I have added it to the system variables as well now. @enzo

Comment: @enzo I receive this error now: ```Command '['dot.bat', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg']' returned non-zero exit status 1. [stderr: b"Error: <stdin>: syntax error in line 1 near 'None'\r\n"]```